# как можно проверить залогинен ли юзер или нет?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

Я использую JSF и JQUERY. И просто надо проверить на клиентской стороне на одной из страниц аутентифицирован ли юзер. Без использования бэкэнда

Есть следующая форма аутентификации.

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/main.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1>#{loginMsg.title}</h1>

        <form name="login" id="login" action="/cms/j_security_check" method="post">

            <h:outputText value="#{loginMsg.try_again}" styleClass="error"
                          rendered="#{param.error}"/>

            <table class="auth">
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="username">#{loginMsg.login}</label></th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="j_username" />
                        <span id="loginError" class="error" style="display: none;">
                            <br/>
                            #{commonMsg.empty_field_error}
                        </span>

                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="password">#{loginMsg.password}</label></th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="j_password" />
                        <span id="passwordError" class="error" style="display: none;">
                            <br/>
                            #{commonMsg.empty_field_error}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" onclick="return auth();" class="login">
                            #{loginMsg.enter}
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;" onclick="return checkForm();"/>
        </form>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="/cms/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("div#outer").addClass('auth');
                var regEx = /^.*MSIE [1-6]\.\d{1}.*$/;
                if (navigator.userAgent.match(regEx)) {
                    window.location = "/cms/403.xhtml"
                }
            });

            jQuery('input').keypress(function(e){
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if(code == 13){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    auth();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });

            function auth() {
                if (checkForm()) {
                    document.forms['login'].submit();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            function checkForm() {
                var res = true;

                jQuery("#loginError").hide();
                jQuery("#passwordError").hide();
                if (!jQuery("#username").val()) {
                    jQuery("#loginError").show();
                    res = false;
                }
                if (!jQuery("#password").val()) {
                    jQuery("#passwordError").show();
                    res = false;
                }

                return res;
            }
        </script>
    </ui:define>
```

Comment: `#{request.remoteUser}` или `#{request.userPrincipal}` не равны null. например `rendered="#{request.remoteUser != null}"`

Comment: @Sergey могу ли я так вывести? <h1>#{request.userPrincipal}</h1>

Comment: Можно. Но если хотите отобразить имя пользователя, то всё же лучше #{request.remoteUser}, ибо это String в отличии от userPrincpal-а, который Principal

Comment: @Sergey напиши в ответе, чтоб я плюсик поставил

Comment: _"Без использования бэкэнда"_: #{request.remoteUser} и #{request.userPrincipal} - это объекты, существующие только на сервере. В Java **Server** Faces большинство операций происходит именно на серверной части.

Условие rendered="#{request.remoteUser != null}" будет обработано на сервере при формировании страницы, а на клиентскую часть (браузер) придёт "чистый" HTML, соответствующий условию

Comment: @bobzer тогда напиши в ответе, я хоть тебе плюсик поставлю)